# Could be Euler product for Riemann zeta function runs over pseudo-prime?

Tags: prime-numbers, pseudoprimes, euler-product

The Euler product over primes defined as :$$\zeta(s)=\prod_{p \ \text{prime}} \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}\tag{01}$$ , My question Here is : is it possible to write  this product $(01)$ for which  run or extends over pseudoprime in any context of it's mathematical definition ( For example Fermat pseudo-prime)

Answer (score 0):

No,
because the product depends
on prime factorization
and so has to use
the actual primes.